# Numerical integration on log binned samples

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I would like to do numerical integration on the function below to get $\omega(r_{p})$ ([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9sje.gif))
$$
  \omega(r_p) = 2\int_{0}^{\infty} \xi(r_p,\pi)\;\mathrm{d}\pi
$$

I have values for $\xi(r_{p},\pi)$ and even though the limits are from 0 to $\infty$, I would like to do it for 0 to $\pi_{\max}$.

***The problem I face is that the values of $\xi(r_{p},\pi)$ are $\log$ binned in the $\pi$ direction, so I have unevenly spaced segments in $\pi$.***

How do I go about doing my numerical integration to get my $\omega(r_{p})$ ?

Comment: If you're using a local rule like the trapezoidal rule or similar, you can just take into account the length of each subinterval. The result isn't the uniform composite rule, but that's fine. You have some problems if you're using a global rule (e.g. Gauss quadrature) however.

Comment: @Ian: So can I go about using the trapezoidal rule taking into account each bin width as I know the values of the bin widths? Just because it is in log, the final result will be the same? What if I have large pi_max values and less bins? Does my accuracy decrease?

Comment: @Ian: Can you also please elaborate on the problems with Gauss quadrature?! I am a rookie as far as math is concerned, I was searching for this particular case, but couldn't find any solutions. Also some websites suggested that trapezoidal cannot be used for uneven intervals!

Comment: The ordinary composite trapezoidal rule can't be used, but you can use the trapezoidal rule on each subinterval separately. If the second derivative doesn't change too much, this will lose accuracy (in that the error will be basically dominated by the error from the large subintervals). But if there are places where the second derivative is relatively large, this will generally *gain* accuracy. This is the idea behind certain forms of  adaptive quadrature.

Comment: Anyway, the problem that I was referring to is that generally speaking a global rule specifies the nodes for you. For example Gauss quadrature is impossible unless you're free to evaluate the integrand wherever you want. In real applications this may be infeasible, because you may only have the integrand at a certain finite set of times and you're stuck with an estimate based on those values.

Comment: As an example, the trapezoidal rule for nodes $x_1<x_2<\dots<x_n$ is $T(f)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{f(x_{i+1})+f(x_i)}{2} (x_{i+1}-x_i)$. This can be simplified to $\frac{f(x_1)(x_2-x_1)}{2}+\frac{f(x_n)(x_n-x_{n-1})}{2}+\sum_{i=2}^{n-2} \frac{f(x_i)(x_{i+1}-x_{i-1})}{2}$.

Comment: @Ian: Just a final note, I just realised that since my bins are in log, at larger scales, the bin width gets very large (it keeps increasing gradually). At these scales, is following the above method the correct choice, as, if I have a larger bin width, then my approximation of the integration is not good enough right?

Comment: This might not be so bad, it really depends on the integrand. It would work well if the second derivative of the integrand decays quickly as (in your notation) $\pi \to \infty$. Try working out the overall error estimate for the log-binned trapezoidal rule to see what happens. The examples of $x^{-p}$, $p>1$ on $[1,\infty)$ may give some insight.

Comment: Also I had a fencepost error; my simplified trapezoidal rule should be up to $n-1$ instead of $n-2$. (This is actually fairly obvious if you try to implement it with $n=3$.)